# Are mnemonic phrase order-sensitive?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

Is it important to remember just the set of the words, or also their order?

If I kept them without the correct order. Can I easily decrypt my wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is important.

If you have 24 different words but don't know the order, you have to try up to *24 factorial* permutations. That is around 620448401733239439360000 different attempts. This may take a very long time and cause you great anxiety, unhappiness and self-recrimination.

---

Related questions:

- [Unsure order of 12 word mnemonic](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/64465/13866)
- [Bruteforcing a seed with 24 words of a unknown order](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/92540/13866)
- [Lost my old-Electrum 12-word mnemonic seed order](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/102422/13866)
- [Bruteforce bitcoin address - I know the words + public address but not the order](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75331/13866)